# Why http://www. goes to /index.php and https://www. does not?

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I'm running into a strange error causing poor SEO results.

Everything works expect when using **http://www.** it shows **/index.php**

but, **https://www.** or **http://** or **https://** does not show **index.php**

This is my rewrite conf

```html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/domain\.com\" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have search console you could check what is wrong with your domain.If you couldn`t find any problem my advice is to find good SEO agency. http://www.asknatewang.com/ There is a chance your ranking to be affected because of the discrepancy.
Greetings!